# Allow user to modify a string extracted from file in terminal and save back to file

Tags: c, file, editor

I would like to create a command line notes editor (written in c on linux platform).

A note is a structure with an author, a date, some text

Requirements are simple:

program can read and print all notes from a file (eventually filtering them by id, date, author)
program will allow the user to modify or create new note and append them to the top of a file.

I can't figure out how i can allow an update.
Point is that i would like to extract for example a note by id putting it in a buffer.
Write the buffer to terminal and let the user to modify it.
When user complete with the note he can confirm and the note will be saved again to file.

How can i do this?

I will accept also to send the temporary note to an editor like nano, 
but wath i want is that program extracts just that note, not to open all the file.

Is there any library to do that or low level system input output interface?

Comment: Most command line utilities that want to let you edit text do it by exec'ing an external editor like `vi` or `emacs`. The user's preferred editor is put in the `EDITOR` environment variable.

Comment: For example, see the `crontab -e` command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Barmar suggested i edit the file with an external editor launching it with `system` system call. I opted to use `tmpfile()` function to create a temporary file where to write or update notes and then copy the stream of byte into original file